Submission approver for signature Docusign
In production, we use endpoint (1) for sending documents for signature in Docusign. We need a new flow where a non-subscriber user receives a pending signature notification, and only when this user approves it, the notice should be sent to the appropriate document subscriber.
Does anyone know which JSON tag or process to adopt for this new flow?
(1)
https://na4.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/<account_id>/envelopes
We use approves without result

What you describe is an envelope that has multiple recipients (let's assume just two recipients for now) and they are in routing order 1 and 2.
If you have routing order set and if it's different, then the system routes the envelope in order and only after the first recipients signs the envelope - the next one gets to sign it.
You provided the endpoint, but not the JSON body you're using, but what you have to do in the JSON body is add the routing order for both recipients like this:
            "signers": [{
                    "name": "VVVVVVV",
                    "email": "v@onecompany.com",
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "recipientId": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "ZZZZZ",
                    "email": "z@onecompany.com",
                    "routingOrder": "2",
                    "recipientId": "2"
                }

